# SoundJs with Angular on Mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, audio, createjs

I am trying to make SoundJS work with angular on mobile devices. The problem is that mobile devices require the sound to be played in direct response to a touch event. However in SoundJS, when user selects a song to play, it has to get loaded first and then gets played when the loadComplete handler is called. SoundJS folks suggest a hack-ish way by launching the entire application (the JavaScript code) from a touch event
http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mobile%20Safe%20Approach/
However, i have no idea how to make this work with angular. Has anyone figured this out ?

Comment: Hi Khalid, I work on SoundJS and that solution you mention was the only way we could find to get audio working everywhere.  Unfortunately I don't have any experience with angular, but in general if you launch [createjs.Sound.initializeDefaultPlugins](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/SoundJS/classes/Sound.html#method_initializeDefaultPlugins) inside of a touch event that should give you reasonably broad support.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey Ojay, thanks for the help, i might try it out some time later, for now i had to replace soundJS with SoundManager2 and it worked with next to no code changes, yours and theirs APIs are very similar.I may visit this later and will report my findings :)

Comment: Are you trying to get it to work inside a controller in AngularJS? I successfully got it to work using SoundJS and compiling with CocoonJS, but it doesn't work anywhere else or with anything else.